# Handling Currency getInstance throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, exceptions

I have a class with a (simplified) method which returns a string like this :

```
private String doStuff(String currencyCode, BigDecimal amount){
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);

    try{
        format.setCurrency(currency);
        sb.append(format.format(amount));
    }catch(Exception e){
        sb.append(amount);
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

However, we sometimes get a `currencyCode` which is not a supported ISO 4217 code, and `Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);` throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.

I've thought of 2 ways to deal with this :

1. use a try/catch around the getInstance call
2. check that the currencyCode is supported before

Option 1 :

```
private String doStuff(String currencyCode, BigDecimal amount){
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
    Currency currency = null;

    try {
        currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        iae.printStackTrace();
    }
    ...
}
```

Option 2 :

```
private static Set<String> currencies = initCurrencies();

private static Set<String> initCurrencies() {
    Set<String> currencies = new HashSet<>();
    for (Currency c : Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()) {
        currencies.add(c.getCurrencyCode());
    }
    return currencies;
}

private String doStuff(String currencyCode, BigDecimal amount){
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
    Currency currency = null;

    if (currencies.contains(currencyCode)) {
        currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
    }
    ...
}
```

Which is better ?

Comment: You haven't looked at the real problem - how is your code going to continue after that exception?

Comment: And interesting that in Swift you would just write “let currency = try? Currency.getInstance(currencyCode)” giving you the exact behaviour of option 2 without the extra lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a third way to handle it, which you didn't mention

3. Let the `doStuff` method throw the `IllegalArgumentException` (or a different type of exception, maybe `InvalidCurrencyException`) and let the calling method handle it (or re-throw it).

Which option you choose depends on what `doStuff` can do if it knows it has an invalid currency code. That is, in both of the options you've presented, what does the `...` actually do with a null `currency` object? Does it throw a `NullReferenceException` later on? Does it return a string indicating the selected currency was invalid? Does it just return an empty string?

If you can do something meaningful with the null currency, then do so. If you can't, though, just let the exception propagate up (maybe wrapping it in a more descriptive exception), as that's what exceptions are supposed to do.

NB: Of the two options you presented, option 2 is better. If exceptions can be avoided, they should be (and printing out the stack trace to users should be avoided at all costs!), as exceptions are not flow control. In option 2, however, you need to consider what happens if the condition in the `if` statement returns false...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you would want a stack trace? If yes, add it to option 2. If not, remove it from option 1.

Your option 2 makes the unnecessary and possibly false assumption that currency codes of available currencies and Currency codes for which getInstance throws no exceptions are the same. I wouldn’t assume that. There may be alternative currency codes. There may be other reasons to throw exceptions.